# Google Play App signing and multiple app store accounts

Tags: android

My understanding of Google Play Managed App signing is that you provide them your existing signing key, and Google then signs the app on your behalf from that point forward. Google provides an interface for you to create/manage Upload keys which Google uses to verify apps before it signs them. I understand the advantage it provides for a developer with a single app store account, if the upload key leaked it could be revoked and a new one generated, however here is my question:

What if you create a templated application that you build and sign for multiple downstream customers (that is, each app is still signed with the same signing key, for every customer). Each of these customers uploads the application you built and signed to their own appstore accounts, does this service offer any kind of management features that come to mind that would benefit this distribution model? A co-worker believes that this service provides a potential multi-tenant key management solution, but it doesn't as far as I can tell. Any comments? Thank you